# How can i modify this function to accept space also inside Text Input

Tags: jquery

I have a function on a Input text which accepts only alphabets , how can i modify this to allow space also so that i can have space between First Name and Last Name

This is my function

```
Name : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"  />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>

$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {

   if(e.which < 65 /* a */ || e.which > 122 /* z */ ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HkEuf/3726/

Answer (score 0):

try this. :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {

   if((e.which < 65 || e.which > 90) && (  e.which < 97 || e.which >122) &&  e.which != 32 )) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Still accepts non-alphabetic, non-space characters between 'Z' and 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

You were also allowing some non-alphabetic characters in there (e.g. 94 == `^`). Just letters & spaces:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {

   if ((e.which == 32)                       || /* space */
       ((e.which >= 65) && (e.which <= 90))  || /* A-Z */
       ((e.which >= 97) && (e.which <= 122))    /* a-z */
      )
     return;
    
     e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"  />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 32
```

To make it:

```
Name : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"  />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>

$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {

   if(e.which < 65 /* a */ || e.which > 122 /* z */ ||
      e.keyCode != 0 || e.keyCode != 32) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
   });
});
```

These keycodes represent spaces in different browsers and should work the way you want I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your function to allow small and capital alphabets and space like this:

```
Name : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity"  />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg"></span>

$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {

   if(e.which < 65 /* a */ || e.which > 122 /* z */ || e.keycode != 32 /* space */) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
   });
});
```